# How can I get notifyDataSetChanged() to start working?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, onitemclicklistener, notifydatasetchanged

I'm trying to change a spinners values based on the selection of an item in another spinner. The values used to populate both spinners are in an xml file called array. The array file looks something like

```
<string-array name="eventYear">
       <item>2010</item>
       <item>2010</item>
       <item>2010</item>
   </string-array>
   <string-array name="eventName">
        <item>something</item>
        <item>something</item>
        <item>something</item>
        <item>something</item>
        .
        .
        .
    </string-array>
```

Here is the onCreate method and other relevant code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_selection);

        // Display UI Elements
        Log.v("RS", "Displaying Headers and Form");
        headerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
        subheaderText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subHeaderTextView);
        headerForm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerForm);

        // For Event Year
        yearTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearTextView);
        yearSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yearSpinner);
        adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.eventYear,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        yearSpinner.setAdapter(adapter0);
        // When a year is selected change the options in the event name spinner
        yearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new myOnItemSelectedListner());

        // For Event Names
        nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.plzSelect,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

        // Add table rows to view
        yearTableRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.yearTableRow);
        nameTableRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.nameTableRow);
    }
```

***adapter0 is a global varibale***

```
private class myOnItemSelectedListner implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count = 0;

            if (count >= 1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Get the year selected from the spinner
                int data = Integer.parseInt(yearSpinner.getItemAtPosition(arg2)
                        .toString());
                Log.v("RS", "Data: " + data);
                // Depending on which year has been selected intialize the
                // new adapter and set it for the event name spinner
                switch (data) {
                case 2010:
                    adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            ReportSelectionActivity.this,
                            R.array.eventName2010,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                case 2011:
                    adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            ReportSelectionActivity.this,
                            R.array.eventName2011,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                case 2012:
                    adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            ReportSelectionActivity.this,
                            R.array.eventName2012,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                default:
                    adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.plzSelect,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                }
                // Add adapter to spinner
                adapter0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter0);
                // Change UI view
                adapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }// End of if statment
            count++;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }// End of private class myOnItemSelectedListener
```

So why isn't the notifyDataSetChanged() not working?

***UPDATED CODE***

```
private class myOnItemSelectedListner implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        String[] array;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // Log.v("RS", "In on onItemSelected");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // int count = 0;

            /* if (count >= 1) { */
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Get the year selected from the spinner
            int data;
            try{
             data = Integer.parseInt(yearSpinner.getItemAtPosition(arg2)
                    .toString());
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                data = 0;
            }
            Log.v("RS", "Data: " + data);
            // Depending on which year has been selected intialize the
            // new adapter and set it for the event name spinner
            switch (data) {
            case 2010:
                Log.v("RS", "Case 2010");
                adapter1.clear();
                array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eventName2010);
                list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
                adapter1.add((CharSequence) list);
                /*
                 * = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 * ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.eventName2010,
                 * android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                 */
                ;
            case 2011:
                Log.v("RS", "Case 2011");
                adapter1.clear();
                array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eventName2011);
                list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
                adapter1.add((CharSequence) list);
                /*
                 * adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 * ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.eventName2011,
                 * android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 */
            case 2012:
                Log.v("RS", "Case 2012");
                adapter1.clear();
                array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eventName2012);
                list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
                adapter1.add((CharSequence) list);
                /*
                 * adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 * ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.eventName2012,
                 * android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 */
            default:
                Log.v("RS", "Case default");
                adapter1.clear();
                array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.plzSelect);
                list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
                adapter1.add((CharSequence) list);
                /*
                 * adapter0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 * ReportSelectionActivity.this, R.array.plzSelect,
                 * android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 */
            }
            // Add adapter to spinner

            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

            // Change UI view
            // Log.v("RS", "notifying view of change");
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            /*
             * }// End of if statment
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }// End of private class myOnItemSelectedListener
```

Comment: If you are recreating the adapter every time it changes then notifyDataSetChanged is redundant

Comment: @eskimoapps.com It wasn't working before I added notifyDataSetChanged. I saw that online and thought it might work. My understanding of it was that to display changed in the view I had to use notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: That is for if you change the data to an existing adapter, since you are recreating it that is not the case for this.  Have you checked that your switch statement is going through correctly?

Comment: @eskimoapps.com.  All of the examples that I've tried so far haven't worked. Right now I'm working on using clear(), then add(), then I use notifyDataSetChanged(). I just changed the part in the switch statement to use the method previously stated instedad of recreating the arrayadapter.

Comment: That would probably be a better way to do it, but that's not what is causing your issue here, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
if (count >= 1) {
```

Obviously count will never be >= 1 if you set it to 0 right beforehand

Comment: Log.v("RS", "Data: " + data); What does this output?

Comment: I was using to see if I was actually getting the correct info from the first spinner

Answer (score 0):

You are creating adapter0 inside a switch which is inside an if which it never goes through because you have:

```
int count = 0;

if (count >= 1) {
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @user2127364 OK now try to replace adapter0 with adapter1 in your switch group to see how it's going...

Comment: I did that. I also found another example online that said using clear, add, and notifyDataSetChanged was better. So I implemented that. Now I'm getting a numberformatexception error. However, I added a try catch block that should be preventing that and I'm still getting that error. I'll add the changes that I made to my intial post.

Comment: @user2127364 Try to use Integer.valueOf instead of Integer.parseInt and remove the lines: adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); and nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1); from the end of your switch, they are not needed. Your approach is goog I think the problem is with the data variable. Also did you notice that your eventYear array in the xml contains only 2010?

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested. Now when it gets to clear() it gives me an unsupportedoperationexception.

Comment: OK that means that your problem was not the notifyDataSetChanged at first place, it was the parsing of the string as integer. What you can do now is to play a little with the adapter, maybe do what you did before (recreating and resetting the adapter to the spinner). However if you still have problems you have to post a new question. Cheers!